# How to exclude some types from tire results?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, tire

```
Tire.search index do
  query do
    filtered do
      query { string term }
      filter :or, { missing: { field: :group_id } },
                  { terms: { group_id: group_ids } }
      filter :not { type: "Movie" } if current_user.has_not_permission("Movie")
    end
  end
end.results
```

I would like to exclude all Movie results if user has not permission to movie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a pretty good answer for authorizing elasticsearch results:

[Authorize elasticsearch results with cancan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600867/authorize-elasticsearch-results-with-cancan)